# Google Cloud Security Account Context not working in Intellij Application Runner

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io

I am unable to authenticate my Dataflow Beam application when I run it in Intellij Idea. This worked for me at one point recently and now it doesn't.

Auth is failing with 403 forbidden **'"Access Denied: Project [myProject]: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project [myProject].'**

1. I have verified that I **DO** have this permission in both my gcp user and service account.
2. I have set **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** with the path to a service account json in my MacOS Zshell profile.
3. This same profile configuration **works** when I run a different **client lib Node JS** app in **VSCode** using the same service account token.
4. This same java Dataflow pipeline **authenticates** when I run/debug it in **Eclipse IDE**.
5. Running **mvn package** from terminal on the same pipeline **is also authenticating** and writing the template to my **GCS storage bucket**.
6. I have added additional service accounts to my gcloud configuration with '**gcloud auth activate-service-account**' and can see them listed with '**gcloud auth list**'
7. I have tried setting the active account to both service accounts.
8. I have tried setting the --serviceAccount Beam option to a service account I know has correct permissions.
9. I would like to try to setting the service token path to the BigQueryIO java Dataflow connector as I am able to do with the Node JS client lib, but it doesn't seem possible?
10. The debugger does work and I can hit a break point.
11. I have tried installing latest and **Version: 2020.1.1 Build: 201.7223.91 29 April 2020**
12. I have tried **uninstalling** and **reinstalling** **Intellij** and creating a new project.

It appears as though this security context is not getting passed to the Dataflow Java Beam library, but the exception output does say '**Inferred default GCP project 'fubotv-prod' from gcloud.**' so apparently some args are getting through.

Perhaps there is some cached response build state or something?

I spent all day stuck on this. I am at my wits end. I would really like to debug my Dataflow pipeline again with Intellij. Any solutions, ideas, random words of encouragement are much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the same version of the libraries in every try? I mean, are using the exact same configuration and library versions when running the pipeline through Maven, Eclipse and Intellij?

Comment: It's the same project built from the same main with the same pom. But the way that Intellij builds/rujs the application seems different. I'm really not even sure how it works. Perhaps the key is in the run configuration? I don't fully understand what Intellij does to build and run a java project...

Comment: I should point out related to this - when I run mvn package this does not actually run the application. This simply builds the template and related jars that are later run on the Dataflow platform as a job. But I know this still requires that google credentials are made available. They are different credentials - GCS write vs. BQ job creation - but these are coming from the same service account. My Node JS client lib still needs the same BQ job create creds though.

Comment: Can you take a look in the logs to see if the user who is trying to access BigQuery is the correct one? (
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#viewing_audit_logs)

Comment: Another question: have you tried to set the service account from your code directly? If you dont, have you tried accessing the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable from your code and printing it to see if its correctly populated?

Comment: Again, this is not a problem if I package with mvn. In this case the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS are picked up. Also, not a problem when use the Node JS client lib and debug the same application with Eclipse - seems to be something specific to Intellij debug?

Comment: I'm not sure how I could further isolate? Is there is a different debug run configuration I could try?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: My best guess now is something with idea_rt.jar

Comment: Ug. So mystery solved and it's just plain dumb. I have only recently started using multiple service accounts. I have been switching between service tokens mapped to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. When I do so, I have been using source to reload my profile to reflect the change. I would then printenv to see the change reflected in terminal. However, Intellij must have it's own shell context that is separate from the IDE terminal window, a flaw imo, and so that was not being updated. On Mac you have to explicitly restart an application and so the shell context was never getting updated.

Comment: Thats what I meant when I asked you to print the env var from your code. So it seems that in fact IntelliJ has its own shell context

Comment: If your problem was solved, consider posting it as an answer or let me know if I can do that

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, a way of debugging what is happening can be printing the var env in your code in `IntelliJ` in order to see if the environment variables are correct

As concluded in the discussion, `IntelliJ` has its own `SHELL` context which makes the OS's variables not accessible if you don't explicitly restart the application.

Comment: Ah, that finally just clicked - to clarify - I did run printenv in the Intellij terminal window and this did not help me identify the issue because it printed the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS associated with that runtime context. In contrast, running the command from my code would have shown the value set in the actual debug runtime context. I just misunderstood what you were suggesting. So yes this would have been the answer - looks like I could have done something along the lines of - Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
      .exec(String.format("sh -c printenv %s", homeDirectory));